# Plotting only certain dates in an array

Tags: date, datetime, matplotlib, plot

I am new to python programming, and have been trying to put together a plot of numbers against dates. The only problem is, when I go to plot it individually seems to show every single date in my range of dates. Consequently the x axis is completely illegible. Is there some way to keep all my data points, but have the x axis only display dates by the month, or something similar?

The code, with some sample data, is as below:

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dates=['1/08/2015', '2/08/2015', '1/09/2015', '2/09/2015', '3/09/2015','4/09/2015', '5/09/2015', '1/10/2015', '2/11/2015', '3/11/2015', '4/11/2015', '5/11/2015', '1/12/2015', '2/12/2015', '1/01/2016', '2/01/2016', '3/01/2016', '1/02/2016', '2/02/2016', '3/02/2016', '4/02/2016', '1/03/2016', '6/03/2016', '1/04/2016', '2/05/2016', '1/06/2016', '1/07/2016', '2/07/2016', '3/07/2016', '4/07/2016', '5/07/2016', '1/08/2016', '2/08/2016', '3/08/2016'] 
converteddates= [dt.datetime.strptime(d, '%d/%m/%Y').date() for d in dates]
data=range(len(converteddates))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%Y'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
plt.plot(converteddates,data)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using MonthLocator (DayLocator's job is to put ticks at everyday):

```
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
plt.plot(converteddates,data)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
```

But a better approach might be:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot_date(converteddates, data)
```

and if it still doesn't like your dates, then set the ticks and labels underneath:

```
ax.set_xticks(converteddates)
strdates = [d.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") for d in converteddates]
ax.set_xticklabels(strdates, rotation="45")
```